# What identification is acceptable to show in Portugal?

Tags: legal, portugal, alcohol, identity-cards

I am traveling to Portugal in July for my brothers birthday, we are going to be attending a music festival that is 18+, what form of ID do you think is acceptable to carry while out in Portugal? I don’t want to be carrying my passport all over the place while I’m there, will restaurants or venues accept a drivers license or a paper copy of my passport?

**edit: I am from the US and have a valid drivers license**

Comment: What is your nationality? Do you have a legal ID card in that country?

Comment: What nationality are you, and what do you have? Driving license for instance?

Comment: Note that if you are not a EU resident you are probably required to have your passport on you at all times anyway...

Comment: I am coming from the US, I have a driver license here

Comment: Note that the minimum drinking age in Portugal is 18 (not 21 as in the US), Since the venue is 18+, I'd suspect that you'd get ID'ed on the door (if they aren't sure), The barstaff shouldn't need to ID you, as they can rely on doorstaff ensuring that everyone inside the venue is old enough.

Comment: I don't think a general answer is possible. Whether a particular document is "acceptable" will depend on who's looking at it (barkeep, festival security, immigration officer, policeman) and for what purpose (buying a beer, getting into a concert, getting into the country receiving a traffic ticket).

Answer (score 1):

Carry your passport. But keep it safe under your clothes in a special pouch.

When you need to proof your age try your driving license, if it is not accepted you can pull out your passport.
If you have a passportcard you could try that, might still not work.

A paper copy of your passport is very unlikely to be accepted, too easy to fake or change details.

In some countries people have to carry their passports I am not sure about Portugal.

Comment: Would be good to get input from a local on whether or not alcohol ID laws are actually enforced in Portugal. I.e. in Czech Republic you can get away with not showing ID at all in most cases.